# how do I re-project points in a camera - projector system (after calibration)

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, projection

i have seen many blog entries and videos and source coude  on the internet about how to carry out camera + projector calibration using openCV, in order to produce the `camera.yml`, `projector.yml` and `projectorExtrinsics.yml` files.

I have yet to see anyone discussing what to do with this files afterwards. Indeed I have done a calibration myself, but I don't know  what is the next step in my own application.

Say I write an application that now uses the camera - projector system that I calibrated to track objects and project something on them. I will use contourFind() to grab some points of interest from the moving objects and now I want to project these points (from the projector!) onto the objects!

what I want to do is (for example) track the centre of mass (COM) of an object and show a point on the camera view of the tracked object (at its COM). Then a point should be projected on the COM of the object in real time.

It seems that `projectPoints()` is the openCV function I should use after loading the yml files, but I am not sure how I will account for all the intrinsic & extrinsic calibration values of both camera and projector. Namely, `projectPoints()` requires as parameters the

- vector of points to re-project (duh!)
- rotation + translation matrices. I think I can use the projectorExtrinsics here. or I can use the composeRT() function to generate a final rotation & a final translation matrix from the projectorExtrinsics (which I have in the yml file) and the cameraExtrinsics (which I don't have. side question: should I not save them too in a file??).
- intrinsics matrix. this tricky now. should I use the camera or the projector intrinsics matrix here?
- distortion coefficients. again should I use the projector or the camera coefs here?
- other params...

So If I use either projector or camera (which one??) intrinsics + coeffs in `projectPoints()`, then I will only be 'correcting' for one of the 2 instruments .   Where / how will I use the other's instruments intrinsics ??

What else do I need to use apart from  `load()` the yml files and `projectPoints()` ? (perhaps undistortion?)

ANY help on the matter is greatly appreciated .
If there is a tutorial or a book (no, O'Reilly "Learning openCV" does not talk about how to use the calibration yml files either!  - only about how to do the actual calibration), please  point me in that direction. I don't necessarily need an exact answer!

Comment: super nice question. can you link me some of the tutorials you mentioned about how to find `projectorExtrinsics.yml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you seem to be confused about the general role of a camera/projector model: its role is to map 3D world points to 2D image points. This sounds obvious, but this means that given extrinsics R,t (for orientation and position), distortion function D(.) and intrisics K, you can infer *for this particular camera* the 2D projection m of a 3D point M as follows: m = K.D(R.M+t). The `projectPoints` function does exactly that (i.e. 3D to 2D projection), for each input 3D point, hence you need to give it **the input parameters associated to the camera in which you want your 3D points projected** (projector K&D if you want projector 2D coordinates, camera K&D if you want camera 2D coordinates).

Second, when you jointly calibrate your camera and projector, you do not estimate a set of extrinsics R,t for the camera and another for the projector, but only one R and one t, which represent the rotation and translation **between the camera's and projector's coordinate systems**. For instance, this means that your camera is assumed to have rotation = identity and translation = zero, and the projector has rotation = R and translation = t (or the other way around, depending on how you did the calibration).

Now, concerning the application you mentioned, the real problem is: **how do you estimate the 3D coordinates of a given point ?**

Using *two cameras* and one projector, this would be easy: you could track the objects of interest in the two camera images, triangulate their 3D positions using the two 2D projections using function `triangulatePoints` and finally project this 3D point in the projector 2D coordinates using `projectPoints` in order to know where to display things with your projector.

With only one camera and one projector, this is still possible but more difficult because you cannot triangulate the tracked points from only one observation. The basic idea is to approach the problem like a *sparse* stereo disparity estimation problem. A possible method is as follows:

1. project a non-ambiguous image (e.g. black and white noise) using the projector, in order to texture the scene observed by the camera.
2. as before, track the objects of interest in the camera image
3. for each object of interest, correlate a small window around its location in the camera image with the projector image, in order to find where it projects in the projector 2D coordinates

Another approach, which unlike the one above would use the calibration parameters, could be to do a dense 3D reconstruction using `stereoRectify` and `StereoBM::operator()` (or `gpu::StereoBM_GPU::operator()` for the GPU implementation), map the tracked 2D positions to 3D using the estimated scene depth, and finally project into the projector using `projectPoints`.

Anyhow, this is easier, and more accurate, using two cameras.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi there , is it possible to talk a little more on this question. on `irc` or any other chat room? I wonder what will happen if I feed 2d points to `projectPoints`. also, isn't the 2nd case you explain a homographic reprojection?

Comment: @nass Let's talk about this in a [StackOverflow chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49454/discussion-between-nass-and-aldurdisciple).

Comment: the chatroom gives me parser errors and I cannot post. is it possible to continue in another one?